# How does Linq use IEnumerable methods after an IOrderedEnumerable method?

Tags: linq, ienumerable, iorderedenumerable

In Linq, extension methods like `Where` return an `IEnumerable` collection, but sorting methods like `OrderBy` return an `IOrderedEnumerable` collection.

So, if you have a query that ends with `OrderBy` (i.e. returns an `IOrderedEnumerable`), you can't later append a `Where` method - the compiler complains about the type being passed into `Where`.

```
var query = Process.GetProcesses()
            .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 10)
            .OrderBy(p => p.Id);

query = query.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 5);
```

However, if you do it all in one query, it's fine!

```
var query = Process.GetProcesses()
            .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 10)
            .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
            .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 5);
```

I've looked at the assembly in Reflector to see if the compiler was re-ordering any of the operations, but it doesn't seem to have. How does this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IOrderedEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>` so you can still use any of the extension methods. The reason your first block of code didn't work is because you had effectively written:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Process> query = Process.GetProcesses()
                                           .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 10)
                                           .OrderBy(p => p.Id);

// Fail: can't assign an IEnumerable<Process> into a variable 
// of type IOrderedEnumerable<Process>
query = query.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 5);
```

That fails because `query.Where(...)` only returns an `IEnumerable<Process>`, which can't be assigned to the `query` variable. It's not calling `Where` that's the problem - it's assigning the result back to the original variable. To demonstrate that, this code will work just fine:

```
var query = Process.GetProcesses()
                   .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 10)
                   .OrderBy(p => p.Id);

// Introduce a new variable instead of trying to reuse the previous one
var query2 = query.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 5);
```

Alternatively, you can declare query to be `IEnumerable<T>` to start with:

```
IEnumerable<Process> query = Process.GetProcesses()
                                    .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 10)
                                    .OrderBy(p => p.Id);

// Fine
query = query.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 5);
```

Comment: Yes, but what is the difference between the two examples? Why does the second one work but the first doesn't?

Comment: The second one doesn't try to assign an `IEnumerable<T>` expression into a variable of type `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.